# Use of "little" meaning young?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Can I use "little" meaning the age?

For example:

> You are still little to do it. Wait until you are 10.

If yes, are there any situations when "little" is preferable over "young"?

Comment: Regardless of whether "little" and "young" are interchangeable, the sentence is incorrect. It needs "too".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Little" also means "young."

From [Oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/little):

> (Of a person) young or younger:
>   *my little brother*

Similarly, you can call your older siblings "My big/older brother/sister."

Both, "young" and "little," are correct and can be used interchangeably, but I will be more inclined to choose "younger." Though "little" is more commonly used.

Do not say "small brother/sister," unless you are referring to their physical attribute.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Little brother" usually means "younger brother", not "young brother". Certainly people use the expression a lot about young kids, but it's not uncommon for people to continue to use the phrase even when they and their brother are adults.

Answer (score 0):

*You're just a little kid. You don't know anything* is a typical thing to say. *Little* does not just refer to the size of the child, but to his young age and inexperience. *Little* refers to everything about the kid being a kid, the child's *"kidness"*.

*Oxford English Dictionary*:

> Of a child or animal: not close to being fully grown, (very) young; (also) younger than a particular relative

Thus, we can also refer to a younger sibling as either *my little sister/brother* or *my kid sister/brother*, and they mean the same thing.